# VirtualBox no acceleration on Windows 10 host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-10, virtualization, acceleration

After upgrading my host OS to Windows 10, I have noticed some problems with my guests so I looked around the settings and noticed that the number of CPUs and acceleration options are greyed out.. I didn't update the virtualbox nor did anything change with my guests since last time, so only I can think of is that the upgrade of host caused this.

Now I wonder if Win 10 introduced some fundamental changes that would somehow affect virtualization or is it only my problem?

VB version 5.0.1
Win10 as a host, Lubuntu as a testing guest (but all guests have the acceleration disabled in them)

**Edit**:
BIOS virtualization settings [image]

Comment: Update VBox the version you are using does not fully support Windows 10

Comment: What is the recommended version? 5.0.4 or 4.3.30 (both are marked as active development)

Comment: Only one indicates specific support for Windows 10.

Comment: upgrading to 5.0.4 did not solve the issue (weren't the Win10 support related to guest as opposed to host which is my case?)

Comment: confirm that your CPUs virtualization extensions are enabled in BIOS.

Comment: @FrankThomas yes they are, see edit please

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is almost guaranteed that Hyper-V has been (re-)enabled.

Go to control panel and turn it off as per the photo.

Do make sure you have the latest VirtualBox as Windows 10 is not supported in versions before 5.x.

[image]

Update for more recent Windows 10 - if you disable Hyper V but have Windows Subsystems for Linux installed then you have to also disable that too.

Comment: Also solves the issue with Windows 8.1

Comment: Sorry for the old topic resurrect, but I don't have the Hyper-V option in the above dialog, is there any alternative? Thanks!

Comment: Which windows version?

Comment: Still working for virtualbox 6.0